# Redis 3.0.5 on Debian Jessie hangs on shutdown when database not in /var/lib/redis. Any ideas?

Tags: redis, debian-jessie

I am trying to configure redis 3.0.5 (DotDeb build) on Debian Jessie to dump the database in another directory instead of the default /var/lib/redis. I know how to do this, and in my wheezy server this same version of redis works flawlessly in another directory. In Jessie, redis starts but cannot write anything to the database. Also, when I try to shut it down, it logs "Failed to dump database, disk is readonly", and the shutdown takes 1-2 minutes instead of the usual 1 second.

The disk is not read only and I have set all the permissions as in the default directory. I even moved /var/lib/redis to /redisdump straight under the root and set the new path in the redis.conf file, but still the error persisted. No matter what I do, as long as the db file is in /var/lib/redis, it will work fine. If I try any other path, it fails.

Previous redis versions do not have this problem. When I set logging level to debug, nothing changes in the amount of information logged, so I have no idea what is causing this.

Any ideas or tips?
Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that those directories are on different file systems? Redis uses rename(2) to move dumps around and that require same FS to work. Also, could it be that you got apparmor or SELinux enabled somehow?

Comment: No, they are both on the same filesystem. Neither AppArmor nor SELinux are enabled. In any case, even if they were, why would one version work but the other no? Thanks!